# Trying to find the number within class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So the class i am looking through has no attribute name. I have tried both of these. When I search =`containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='today_nowcard-temp')` it returns the line that has the value i want. But i have no way of extracting the number. Because the line i want has no class attribute name i cant get the number directly from the find function. if i do `containers = soup.find('span', class_=None` it doesn't return the vale i want. This is the whole thing of what i have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://weather.com/en-CA/weather/today/l/8663b88e4a1c7d6068b7f33e360396ac1c89f3dde9533082cd342aef06ad1e87'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='today_nowcard-temp')


print(containers)
```

Comment: Can't you simply use regex to get the number out of your string? Also, could you please add the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find`() instead of `find_all`() and then do `find_next('span')`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://weather.com/en-CA/weather/today/l/8663b88e4a1c7d6068b7f33e360396ac1c89f3dde9533082cd342aef06ad1e87'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.find('div', class_='today_nowcard-temp')
print(containers.find_next('span').text)
```

If you want to use find_all() then iterate it like below.

```
containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='today_nowcard-temp')
for item in containers:
   print(item.find_next('span').text)
```

Or you can use css selector.

```
print(soup.select_one("div.today_nowcard-temp > span").text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! One more thing, the degrees symbol is being printed as a question mark thingy. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I am getting proper value on console no question mark.